# Leveraging Google Youtube .NET Client SDK targetting .NET 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, tags, google-api-dotnet-client, youtube.net-api

The Google YouTube v3 client SDK for .NET is targeted for .NET 4.5, however I am looking at using it in my application which targets .Net 4.0.

Does Google provide any SDK targeting 4.0, or does the application implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I use it with .NET 4.0. 
I installed via the Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager Console using the command:

```
       Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3
```

Also, I had to install Windows 7 update KB2468871 and all outstanding updates via Windows Update.

Comment: My application would be used by a number of users, cannot assure all update their system.

Comment: You might consider including something in your documentation that indicates that your software may not operate if the underlying Windows operating system and the .NET 4.0 Framework is not up-to-date.

Comment: That would not be a smooth user experience though. Has anyone tried without using the client SDK?

Comment: I forgot to tell you that it was in July, 2014 that I first used the .NET 4.0 Framework with the YouTube V3 API. That was when I updated with the latest Windows Update patches on Windows 7. If your users have updated near or after July, 2014, they should be OK.

Comment: Thanks. Any other option ? any other google client SDK which does not use bcl

Comment: I don't think there us another option. Use the .NET 4.0 Framework. It will work.